# unhighlight the row background when another row is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, contextmenu, mousedown

I am using [jQuery-contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html). I am trying to highlight the row background on left or right click.

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'tr', function() {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000');
});
```

Somehow the contextMenu is making it unstable. Could you please suggest me how can I triger the background Color before contextMenu?
PLease see the jsfiddle below to have a better idea. I also need to unhighlight the previous row background when another row is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/904/

Comment: I can fix the unhighlight, but I don't understand the first part you need: "how can I trigger the background Color before contextMenu" ? Could you rephrase or explain better?

Comment: As you can see on jsfiddle the background color doesn't change on right click. I presume jQuery-contextMenu is triggering way before my function.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to have one row with a background color at any given time, it's not that the jQuery plugin is messing your code. It's just that you never "unpaint" it. This is how I'd do it:

```
var highlighted;
$('body').on('mousedown', 'tr', function() {
    if(highlighted) highlighted.css('backgroundColor', 'white');
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'lightseagreen');
  highlighted = $(this);
});
```

You store the element that's highlighted and you change it back everytime you paint some other row.

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/909/

Comment: Thank yo for that. When right click on a row the background becomes green and the contextmenu is showing showing up then if I right click to another row the background doesn't change. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I'm not used to jQuery (I don't like it, really) but let me look at it :)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Dan Philip suggested to apply css for #context-menu-layer and it worked. So, no need :)

Comment: I thought it worked but it is still not working please see the latest jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/914/ when display is none the context menu disappears straight away. I would appreciate if you can see if there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically normal mouse events are triggered on both left and right click but if you're looking for the right click event.

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", "tr", function(event){
 .
 .
 .
});
```

In your case `mousedown` is enough to listen to both left and right clicks

```
$("body").on("mousedown", "tr", function(event){
  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active"); 
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

And a little bit of CSS

```
table.dataTable tbody tr.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/910/ this didn' t work where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Edited the answer. It was a selector priority issue in CSS.

Comment: Please see the edited jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/911/. My main problem is that when I right click to a row, the background changes then the contextmenu appears. But when I go and right click to another row the context menu re-opens on another row and the background doesn't change when I immediately right click to an another row. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: When you open up the custom context menu there is layer ` #context-menu-layer ` added to DOM covering the entire body preventing mouse events on the body untill the context menu is closed. This is being added though the plugin script file. It can be fixed by applying CSS display on that layer. Edited the answer for the fix.

Comment: I thought it worked but please see the latest jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/914/ when display is none the context menu disappears straight away. I would appreciate if you can see if there is a way to make this work.

Comment: The plugin works in a way in which it adds the overlay layer to cover the entire screen so that when the user clicks outside the menu the menu closes.

Comment: and we are clicking to overlay not the row. that's why the background doesn't change right? so, there is no solution for it? when the context menu triggers on right click can we make this js code to run within jquery.contextMenu.min.js file?

Comment: we will probably have to edit the plugin file which is difficult and not recommended.

Comment: it is not end of the world but just annoying. will deal with it later. Probably will have to change the contextmenu plugin. thank you again for the help.

Comment: Happy to help. All the best in fixing the issue.